# Where can i find it on a keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, pycharm, hotkeys

What's the interesting button? Where can i find it on a keyboard? This notification appeared in Pycharm programme.

[image]

Comment: That's ALT on a Mac.

Comment: It's the ESCAPE key on a Mac.